# How to import Eigen C++ library in Matlab 2016b?

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

Trying to run  this command in matlab:

```
mex nameofthemainfile.cpp
```

It throws out the following error:

> Error using mex
>   nameofthemainfile.cpp
>   ...\source\NameOfAnotherFile.h(10): fatal
>   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Eigen/Core': No such file or directory

I am using VS2015 c++ compiler. Do I need to use another one?

Comment: No it's not a compiler problem. Matlab's mex calls in c/c++ must respect the matlab's mex protocol: the entry point of a mex call is the function `void mexFunction(...)`, which I (strongly) suppose to be missing in the Eigen c++ library. The error you get may be solved by adding the path to include Eigen's headers, but unfortunately this will not help you.

Comment: In what path do you have the Eigen headers? You need to add that to the search path for the `mex` command.

Comment: There are so many header files within the folders in Eigen/src/ 
How do I add the src folder to the search? I tried -I/Eigen/src/ Doesn't seem to work

Comment: If you installed Eigen to `C:/stuff/Eigen`, then add `-IC:/stuff/` to your mex-command.

Comment: That worked. thanks! I wasn't using the parent folders... do I need to close this issue if it is solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compile c++ libraries with mex to use them in matlab, but you can write a wrapper (let's say `MexEigen.cpp`) where the entry point `void mexFunction(...)` internally makes use of the Eigen library. Then, when compiling it with mex remember to add the include path for Eigen headers:

```
mex MexEigen.cpp -I[PATH_TO_EIGEN_INCLUDE]
```